# Breaker Trips When Light Switch Is Turned On

Tags: electrical

I went to help install a chandelier today and this is the sequence of events:

- There was no light fixture in pace when I arrive. The previous owners had removed a fixture and my friend, who's lived there for two years, just got around to buying one.
- At the fixture box, there was a black, white, and ground, all with wire nuts on them.
- I connected the new fixture. Before I hung it, I put a bulb in and tested it. Everything worked fine.
- I affixed the new light to the box and tested again. I heard a loud pop at the switch (a dimmer switch). The breaker at the panel had tripped.
- Thinking it was the dimmer, I purchased a new dimmer and tried again. Another pop and the breaker tripped again.'

-After resetting the breaker, I bypassed the switch completely and the light worked.

- I then purchased a single pole switch (no dimmer). I installed it and tested the light. It worked.
- I put the switch back into the wall and tested again. It tripped the breaker.
- I took the switch back out of the box and tried again. Tripped the breaker again.

From everything that's visible, there are no shorts.

Ideas?

Comment: How old is the wiring you're working with here? Can you post photos?

Comment: Does the dimmer require a neutral wire?

Comment: Does the breaker have a "TEST" button on it?\

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would bet you pinched a wire in the light assembly when putting it back. The switch blew as it was the weak link, or this is where I would be looking. If there are no visible arc marks in the switch or light call an electrician and make sure they have a megger available. A megger is a high voltage ohm meter that will make it possible to find pinched wires that may intermittently work.

Comment: I've been guilty of tightening a mounting screw right into a wire and shorting it.